# How to render YUV data by using DirectX11

Tags: render, yuv, direct3d11

Now, I have a work is to render YUVI420 data use Direct11.1, and I can render RGB data yet, but I cant find any information for render YUV directly.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can create NV12 format texture and create shaderResourceView to map Luma and Chroma data, then use shader to draw it.

You can refer this project which i learned from.[D3D11NV12Rendering](https://github.com/balapradeepswork/D3D11NV12Rendering)

Finally, i encourage you to use D3D11 VideoProcessor method to render a frame.

Comment: Hi, You can renference this code sample to render a yuv data, it can be nv12 or convert yuv to rgba, [dx11_video_player](https://github.com/windboy12138/dx11_video_player)